# Run ruby script with tracing output like set -x in bash

Tags: ruby

Does ruby have some way to execute a ruby script in tracing mode?

For example: If we execute a bash script with `set -x` it shows input and output of the command being executed. Is there a way to accomplish this in ruby?

Answer (score 2):

### Built-In Debugger

Step through your code with the built-in debugger. Invoke your script with:

```
ruby -rdebug /path/to/script
```

and step through it with <kbd>s</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd>. See the [DEBUGGER_ class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/debug/rdoc/DEBUGGER__.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run arbitrary scripts, then you can use `irb`.

```
$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > tmp = 'test'
 => "test" 
2.3.0 :002 > class Tmp
2.3.0 :003?>   end
 => nil 
2.3.0 :004 > Tmp
 => Tmp
```

Every time you run a command, you get the expression's result.

Answer (score 0):

Since `set -x` is by no means “debugging,” here goes the implementation of the same functionality in pure ruby:

```
ruby -e '
  code = File.readlines("/path/to/file.rb")
  eval code.map { |c| %Q|puts "+ #{c.strip}"| }.zip(code).join($/)
'
```